# DNS cache on macOS (Catalina)

Tags: macos, dns

Can somebody share with me a way to display the DNS cache on my MacOS, Catalina (10.15.4)?

Comment: May be this answer may help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54151812/4440387

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely you don't actually have a DNS cache. If you do, `dscacheutil -cachedump` seems relevant here, probably `sudo dscacheutil -cachedump`. That said, I don't see any cache on any system I have, neither server-oriented systems nor end-user laptops.

See `man dscacheutil` for more.

Denis' answer via the comment will let you see lookups as they happen, but the DNS cache is very short lived if present at all.

Is there an actual problem at hand?